# How to fix Unregistered or expired token error using AWS Push notification service

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, push-notification

I am trying to integrate AWS push notification service with IOS platform but it gives me unregistered or expired token error on sending notification from console.

I have registered device through amazon API which shows active status. Followed all steps for creating SSL certificates, setting up AWS SDKs, tried generating different certificates of production and sandbox too.

```swift
var pinpoint: AWSPinpoint?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        registerForPushNotifications()
        
        /** start code copy **/
        // Create AWSMobileClient to connect with AWS
        AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().initialize { (userState, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error initializing AWSMobileClient: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else if let userState = userState {
                print("AWSMobileClient initialized. Current UserState: \(userState.rawValue)")
            }
        }
        
        // Initialize Pinpoint
        let pinpointConfiguration = AWSPinpointConfiguration.defaultPinpointConfiguration(launchOptions: launchOptions)
        pinpoint = AWSPinpoint(configuration: pinpointConfiguration)
        /** end code copy **/
        
        
        
        
        return true
    }

//FOR REGISTERING PUSH NOTIFICATIONS
  func registerForPushNotifications() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
            (granted, error) in
            print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
            // 1. Check if permission granted
            guard granted else { return }
            // 2. Attempt registration for remote notifications on the main thread
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        }
    }

//GENERATED TOKEN
    pinpoint!.notificationManager.interceptDidRegisterForRemoteNotifications(
            withDeviceToken: deviceToken)
        
        let deviceToken = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
        print("Token: \(deviceToken)")
```

After following all steps I get unregistered or expired token error.

> Request Id 640 : {"errorMessage":"Unregistered or expired
> token","channelType":"APNS","pushProviderStatusCode":"400","pushProviderError":"BadDeviceToken","pushProviderResponse":"{"reason":"BadDeviceToken"}"}

Comment: I am having the same issue as well, have you figured out how to fix this?

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue but its happening on Android as I did not try on IOS. AWS Push notification (with firebase) is working but after sometime when app is idle on background, i come with same error "Unregistered or expired token". did anyone find the solution?? Thanks